# How to solve trigonometric equations with a domain involving negative values of $x$?

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

I don't seem to understand the concept of a negative domain when solving trigonometric equations on "another interval" For example:

> Solve $\cos x=-\sqrt{3}/2$  given that the domain is  $-\pi \le x\le \pi$.

I don't know what to do or understand the process at all! Please help, thank you!

Comment: there's a nice interactive exhibit at http://www.mathopenref.com/trigterminalside.html that allows you to drag a point on the terminal side and see what angle (including negative ones) it results in.

Answer (score 4):

$$\cos x=-\frac{\sqrt3}2=-\cos\frac\pi3=\cos\left(\pi-\frac\pi3\right)$$

$$x=2m\pi\pm\left(\pi-\frac\pi3\right)$$ where $m$ is any integer

Now find $m$ such that $-\pi\le x\le\pi$

Answer (score -1):

Simple. $x = -pi/6 $ will do nicely. To see this, note that cos is periodic with period $\pi$. This means that $x+\pi = x$ for all $x$. Note however this does not mean that $x=x-\pi$ for all $x$. Anyway, you can find the answer in the interval $0<x<\pi$, then just translate the interval.