# How to solve trigonometric equations with a negative domain? Solve $2\sin(2x+π)+\sqrt{3}=0$, Domain : $\{-\pi\le x\le 3\pi\}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Solve $2\sin(2x+π)+\sqrt{3}=0$, Domain : $\{-\pi\le x\le 3\pi\}$

My Working
Let $u = 2x + \pi.$
Changed the domain to $-\pi \le x \le 3\pi$, so $\sin(u)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, with base angle $\frac{\pi}3$.

So If I have to go $-180^\circ$, there are two quadrants in which $u$ can be negative, that is quadrant III and IV.

So I subtracted $2\pi-\frac{\pi}3=\frac{4\pi}3$. Then, added $\pi+\frac{\pi}3=\frac{4\pi}3.$

Now I asked self that on a round of $2 \pi$, what angles will I hit where $\sin$ is negative? The negative angles are still in quadrants III and IV.

So I added $2\pi + 5\frac{\pi}3=11\frac{\pi}3$. Then did the same to $4\frac{\pi}3$ from which I got $10\frac{\pi}3$.

Now I did,  $2x +  \pi  = \frac{5\pi}3, \;4\dfrac{\pi}3, \;11\dfrac{\pi}3, \;10\dfrac{\pi}3,$ then subtracted the  $\pi$  from all the answers and then divided by $2$.

Thus, $x =  \frac{\pi}3,\;\frac{\pi}6,\;2\frac{\pi}3,\;7\frac{\pi}6$.

Now this answer is actually wrong and I don't understand why. I believe it's due to my understanding of the concept with negative radians in the domain. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

I looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1010437) question. But didn't understand the solution especially the part with the variable $m$ is coming from nowhere and what you're suppose to with that variable.

Comment: you must include your text in Dollar signs

Comment: where should I put the dollar signs?

Comment: write $$\sin(x)$$

Comment: I tried putting a dollar sign near the less than sign, didn't work

Comment: $$...$$ and the text in Dollar signs

Comment: done, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Here is a [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/) for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write $$\sin(2x+\pi)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ and Substitute $$t=2x+\pi$$ then you have to solve
$$\sin(t)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
and this is what i got:
$$x=-\frac{5 \pi }{6}\lor x=-\frac{2 \pi }{3}\lor x=\frac{\pi }{6}\lor x=\frac{\pi }{3}\lor x=\frac{7
   \pi }{6}\lor x=\frac{4 \pi }{3}\lor x=\frac{13 \pi }{6}\lor x=\frac{7 \pi }{3}$$

Comment: I already did that part, that was one of the first things I did.

Comment: then you must substitute back and look if your solution is situated in the given interval

Comment: What do you mean? I did that

Comment: @jame_smith I believe he meant verifying your solutions. For instance one of your early mistake is to consider $u=\pi+\frac{\pi}3$ a solution to $\sin(u)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$.
Edit: if your end solutions are wrong, you must have made a mistake somewhere. If you really have no idea where that mistake is, you can always backtrack your results/reasoning, and check their consistency.

Comment: but it is, it was like one of the 2 solutions I got right and I did backtrack my results I really don't understand my mistake

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner hang on a sec, how did u get so many solutions when there r only 4 possible?

Comment: make a plot of your function $\sin(2x+\pi)$

Comment: @jame_smith Let me apologize, you are correct about that. That value of $u$ is a solution. Your "mistake" actually comes after that. Disregarding your method and the number of solutions, you should not have gotten the value $\frac{2\pi}3$. Redo that part and you should obtain another of Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's solutions.

Comment: @N.Bach that's the problem I don't know how to re-do that part.

Comment: @jame_smith What I was hinting at, was that you made a simple error in your computations. If my understanding is correct, you found $4$ possible values for $u$, then computed $4$ values of $x$ based on that. I can match $3$ of your $x$-values to $3$ of your $u$-values [based on your method], but not the fourth value, $x=\frac{2\pi}3$. That value of $x$ should have come from $u=\frac{11\pi}3$. That is a computational mistake.

Comment: @jame_smith Beyond that, the rough idea behind your method is okay. The "real" problem is that you aren't computing every possible solutions. For that particular problem, Yves Daoust's answer, and the other question you found, implicitly explain the problem: you didn't look at enough $u$-values.

Comment: @N.Bach What did I do wrong with the 4th value? and how did I get the 3rd value wrong I checked my stuff in my calculator.

Comment: @jame_smith When I said `the fourth value` I meant "the only $x$-value I couldn't match with a $u$-value". So the "3rd value" in your list. About that 3rd value, try computing "$2\times (\frac{2\pi}3)+\pi$" and tell me if it's the same as "$\frac{11\pi}3$".

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The period of the sine is two pi and supplementary angles have the same sine. So

$$\sin x=s$$ has the solutions

$$2k\pi+\arcsin s, \\(2k+1)\pi-\arcsin s.$$

For your $s$, find all $k$ that make the value fall in the requested range.

Comment: Might be too much to ask but is there a simpler way u can explain it to me cos that just went over my head

Comment: @jame_smith: plug your $s$ in my equations and try several $k$.